# How to add/remove Exchange 2003 components in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2003

Dear friends how I install or add the SMTP and NNTP services on Windows Server 2008 for Exchange Server 2003.   These services are not present in add roles.

Can I install 2003 Exchange Server in W2K8 Server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is because Exchange 2003 doesn't work on Windows 2008.

From 'The Exchange Team' on [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2007/08/16/3403679.aspx):

> Exchange 2003 Service Pack 2 will be similarly supported: **Exchange 2003 cannot be installed on Windows Server 2008**, but will be supported with Windows Server 2008 domain controllers.

From MS KB948680 [Description of the Microsoft server applications that are supported on Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948680) (Under "*Applications that are incompatible*"):

> - Microsoft Exchange Server 2003